# Python slack RTMClient Causes 100% CPU

Tags: python, docker, centos, slack, slack-api

python version: 3.7

OS version(s): Centos in Docker

I am developing a Slack chatbot in Python
Acting as a Docker container

The problem is that the container suddenly takes 100% of the CPU
CPU doesn't grow slowly, suddenly takes 100%
The same thing happens if you delete everything in slack_translate

In fact, the issue occurs even if you are running python without doing anything in the slack workspace.

Please advise if you have any problems

Here is my source

```
import os
import time
import slack

project_name = os.environ['project_name']
source = os.environ['source']
target = os.environ['target']
slack_api_token = os.environ['slack_api_token']
translation = os.environ['translation']
translation_token = os.environ['translation_token']
environment = os.environ['environment']

@slack.RTMClient.run_on(event='message')
def slack_translate(**payload):

    event = payload['data']
    if 'subtype' not in event:

        channel_id = event['channel']
        thread_ts = event['event_ts']
        user = event['user']
        webclient = payload['web_client']
        message = event['text']

        webclient.chat_postMessage(
            channel=channel_id,
            text=message
        )
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    rtm_client = slack.RTMClient(token=slack_api_token)
    rtm_client.start()
```

Here is Docker stats log

```
2019-11-25 21:50:01
CONTAINER ID        NAME                           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
c95fb2dcfe78        bot_test                       0.00%               24.25MiB / 7.638GiB   0.31%               7.4MB / 304kB       129MB / 38MB        5
0b98033669ce        docker_www_1                   0.01%               36.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.46%               406kB / 908kB       41kB / 86.5kB       11
c753e1012f12        translateproject_translate_1   0.01%               98.81MiB / 7.638GiB   1.26%               12MB / 4.91MB       541kB / 0B          10
0b4c8f3ad089        mainback_db_1                  0.09%               224.4MiB / 7.638GiB   2.87%               4.27MB / 7.04MB     60.4MB / 128MB      34
da9bce2cb343        mainback_phpmyadmin_1          0.00%               66.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.85%               3.2MB / 5.21MB      62.8MB / 438kB      11


2019-11-25 22:00:01
CONTAINER ID        NAME                           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
c95fb2dcfe78        bot_test                       0.00%               24.25MiB / 7.638GiB   0.31%               7.4MB / 308kB       129MB / 38MB        5
0b98033669ce        docker_www_1                   0.00%               36.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.46%               406kB / 908kB       41kB / 86.5kB       11
c753e1012f12        translateproject_translate_1   0.00%               98.81MiB / 7.638GiB   1.26%               12MB / 4.91MB       541kB / 0B          10
0b4c8f3ad089        mainback_db_1                  0.10%               224.4MiB / 7.638GiB   2.87%               4.27MB / 7.04MB     60.4MB / 128MB      34
da9bce2cb343        mainback_phpmyadmin_1          0.00%               66.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.85%               3.2MB / 5.21MB      62.8MB / 438kB      11


2019-11-25 22:10:01
CONTAINER ID        NAME                           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
c95fb2dcfe78        bot_test                       0.00%               24.25MiB / 7.638GiB   0.31%               7.41MB / 312kB      129MB / 38MB        5
0b98033669ce        docker_www_1                   0.00%               36.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.46%               406kB / 908kB       41kB / 86.5kB       11
c753e1012f12        translateproject_translate_1   0.01%               98.81MiB / 7.638GiB   1.26%               12MB / 4.91MB       541kB / 0B          10
0b4c8f3ad089        mainback_db_1                  0.09%               224.4MiB / 7.638GiB   2.87%               4.27MB / 7.04MB     60.4MB / 128MB      34
da9bce2cb343        mainback_phpmyadmin_1          0.01%               66.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.85%               3.2MB / 5.21MB      62.8MB / 438kB      11


2019-11-25 22:20:01
CONTAINER ID        NAME                           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
c95fb2dcfe78        bot_test                       101.85%             24.25MiB / 7.638GiB   0.31%               7.41MB / 312kB      129MB / 38MB        5
0b98033669ce        docker_www_1                   0.00%               36.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.46%               406kB / 908kB       41kB / 86.5kB       11
c753e1012f12        translateproject_translate_1   0.00%               98.81MiB / 7.638GiB   1.26%               12MB / 4.91MB       541kB / 0B          10
0b4c8f3ad089        mainback_db_1                  0.10%               224.4MiB / 7.638GiB   2.87%               4.27MB / 7.04MB     60.4MB / 128MB      34
da9bce2cb343        mainback_phpmyadmin_1          0.00%               66.26MiB / 7.638GiB   0.85%               3.2MB / 5.21MB      62.8MB / 438kB      11
```

Comment: Try running you code on a different machine and see if you will be able to reproduce the same issue. Also running a profiler will be helpful so as to know where the issue arises from. You can attach the profiler results here too.

Comment: @CalebNjiiri   Thank you for your reply!!!!  However, the same problem occurs even though we have the same environment in aws eC2